# reading related data after a selection of a foreign key - MVC3 and EF4

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, entity-framework

I am new to MVC and EF and I have a question. 
I have built a site with models views controllers etc. 
On an edit view for a Case (pretty big model so I won't post it here) I have a FK to a Customer model using CustomerID. When a user selects a customer id from a drop down list, I would like to display CustomerName, CustomerPhone etc after the selection of the ID. I think I might need to do a post back for this to work?

Also, do I need to Include the related entities as part of the initial data "get"? I have read some detail on that but I dont fully understand how that needs to work.

Please let me know if I should post more info. Thanks!

Here is my ActionResult for Edit

```
public ActionResult Edit(int id)
    {
        Cases cases = db.Cases.Find(id);

        //related data needs to loaded to show related data fields
        //include related data entities
        var v = db.Cases.Include("Customers");

        ViewBag.TechnicianID = new SelectList(db.Technicians, "TechnicianID", "LastName", cases.TechnicianID);
        ViewBag.BranchID = new SelectList(db.Branches, "BranchID", "BranchName", cases.BranchID);
        ViewBag.EngineModelID = new SelectList(db.EngineModels, "EngineModelID", "EngineModelName", cases.EngineModelID);
        ViewBag.CaseCategoryID = new SelectList(db.CaseCategories, "CaseCategoryID", "CategoryName",cases.CaseCategoryID);
        ViewBag.Qualified = new SelectList(new[] { "YES", "NO", "PARTIALLY" });
        ViewBag.CaseStatus = new SelectList(new[] { "OPEN/IN PROCESS", "CLOSED" });
        return View(cases);
    }
```

The line
    var v = db.Cases.Include("Customers")
is what I am trying to use to load related customer data and then show in my edit view like this:

```
@Html.EditorFor(model => model.Customer.CustomerName)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well it depends on what you are trying to do. You could include a model which holds all the required data and send it with every call on that page (initial empty ofcourse)
Once you selected the customer, do post-back and send the customerId to your application and return the same page with the desired model.
You could do that via AJAX too.

> Also, do I need to Include the related entities as part of the initial data "get"?

Not sure if I understand what you are trying to say. You mean that you think you would have to send all customer's data down to the page and select the related data on client side?

Comment: Thanks.
The first thing I am trying to do is load related data based on a FK.
See my Edit of my question where I added an ActionResult called Edit.

Comment: If you want to send all customers down to the client you have to select the correct customer via javascript like so:

Comment: var customers = @Html.Raw( Json.Encode(Model.Customers) );
and then you can iterate over the customers in javascript and select the desired one